# lua number format not working

Tags: lua

I have the following function:

```
function timestamp(duration)
    local hours = duration / 3600
    local minutes = duration % 3600 / 60
    local seconds = duration % 60
    return string.format("%02d:%02d:%02.03f", hours, minutes, seconds)
end
```

when the duration is 4.404 sec it returns 00:00:4.404

what is am looking for is 00:00:04.404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
string.format("%02d:%02d:%06.3f", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

**Field width** contains all characters of the number, including *point* and fraction.

Comment: i will check it

Comment: That could work, but please note that using the `0` flag together with a precision for the `f` format causes undefined behavior (Lua uses `sprintf` under the hood).

Comment: also i want to remove . from seconds is it possible and replace with _ (underscore)

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Add `:gsub("%.", "_")` after `string.format()` like `string.format():gsub()` ;)

Comment: @siffiejoe - Can you point to the source of this information?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: From the C standard's explanation on printf flags: "0  For d, i, o, u, x, X, e, E, f, g and G conversions, leading zeros (following any indication of sign or base) are used to pad to the field width; no space padding is performed.  If the 0 and - flags both appear, the 0 flag will be ignored.  For d, i, o, u, x and X conversions, if a precision is specified, the 0 flag will be ignored.  For other conversions, the behavior is undefined." But I just realized that you can interpret it in a different way, so never mind ...

Comment: @siffiejoe - I did not understand: is `%06.3f` safe or is it UB?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: The UB could apply to `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversions with a specified precision (what I originally thought), or (more likely) to non-`d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversion in general.